# HiveQL: find Nth value in a one-to-many table

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

I have a simple table:

```
UserID  EventTimestamp
...     ...
```

User can have any number of events (from none to lots). I need to run a *HiveQL* query that would extract the timestamp of the 3rd event (in the ascending order). Having fewer than 3 events should result in null.

Is there a solution that doesn't require emulating *rank()* using a UDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use a MySQL query, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT
  e1.UserID,
  MIN(e3.EventTimestamp) ThirdTimestamp
FROM
  Events e1 LEFT JOIN Events e2
  ON e1.UserID=e2.UserID and e1.EventTimestamp<e2.EventTimestamp
  LEFT JOIN Events e3
  ON e1.UserID=e3.UserID and e2.EventTimestamp<e3.EventTimestamp
GROUP BY
  UserID
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddfbc/1).

Answer (score 1):

This should work.    The inner query uses DISTRIBUTE BY and SORT BY to sort the timestamps by userid; then times are popped into an array via collect_set. Then get the 3rd element.

I couldn't make collect_set behave inside sub1, so I structured it thisaway, although I suspect there must be a more efficient way.

```
    SELECT userid, time[2] FROM
(SELECT userid, collect_set(eventtimestamp) time FROM
(SELECT userid , eventtimestamp 
FROM myTable
DISTRIBUTE BY userid
SORT BY eventtimestamp ASC 
LIMIT 3) sub1
GROUP BY userid ) sub2
GROUP BY userid, time[2]
```